# Разные разрешения доступа к файлам, созданным PHP-FPM в Docker-контейнере

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, permissions

Есть консольная PHP-команда (Laravel), которая просто пишет дату в лог.

На домашней системе запускаю:

```
docker compose exec php-cli php artisan app:test
```

Создаётся `laravel.log` со следующими разрешениями (`getfacl laravel.log`):

```
# file: laravel.log
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:w3lifer:rwx                #effective:rw-
group::r-x                      #effective:r--
group:www-data:rwx              #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Запускаю на рабочей:

```
# file: laravel.log
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

---

**Вопрос, собственное в том, где это настраивается?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем дело было в ACL ...

Я когда-то на домашней системе устанавливал ACL для директории с проектами (`~/pr`) для своего пользователя и пользователя `www-data` в `rwx`, чтобы не возиться со всяким ошибками аля "Permission denied".

Сбросил ACL на домашней системе:

```
setfacl -bR ~/pr
```